# How to use multiple conditional statement using python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to execute an multiple conditional statement, If the condition passes then only further process can be executed.

I am using AND to concatenate two conditions but it gives error as **ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

Script that i am using so far:

```
if df['column1']=='Del Ind' and df['column5'].notna():
   i = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((df['state_name'],d))
   def f(x) : return Levenshtein.ratio(*x)
   out = pd.DataFrame.from_records(i,columns=['Inp','Output']).assign(Score=i.map(f))
   out = out.loc[out.groupby('Inp')['Score'].idxmax()]
```

How to correct this line of code :

**if df['column1']=='Del Ind' and df['column5'].notna():**

I can execute the code if i am not using the if statement, But while using under if condition it doesn't satisfy.

Please suggest how to execute.

Comment: df['column5'].notna() ur explicitly converting null to False there is issue
change that or remove that party of if statement.

Comment: difficult to say what's going wrong without any data.  To understand the specific error message: what should be the output of `[1,2,3,4,5] > 2`?  Pandas is flagging the fact that the condition may have multiple (boolean) values as a response

Comment: @anon01  -  The if condition is giving error while using df['column5'].notna():, What is wrong in this line .

Comment: Just before the if statement, can you add this line and say what it prints? `print(df['column5']); print(df['column5'].notna()); `

Comment: I have checked and it is giving as per expected, for which i have used the condition. for this df['column5'].notna() i am getting in True, False.

Comment: `df['column5'].notna()` returns a `DataFrame` not a boolean. So your if becomes: `if df['column1']=='Del Ind' and DataFrameObject:`. `DataFrameObject` is not a boolean value i.e. is does not return `True` or `False`. What are you exactly checking in the second condition?

Comment: Sometimes Python doesn't like it when you're doing too many things in one line. Try setting `df['column5'].notna()` to a variable and then using that variable in the conditional instead.

Comment: @ObjectJosh -  Have tried the same way but still same issue

Answer (score 1):

#### We need to use bitwise operations instead.

Instead of:

```py
if df['column1']=='Del Ind' and df['column5'].notna():
```

Write:

```py
if df['column1']=='Del Ind' & df['column5'].notna():
```